# Displaying model's docstring in admin app

Tags: python, django, django-admin

In Django admin, `help_text` attribute for individual fields is displayed to give instructions. However, I would like to include a similar feature for the whole models.

In the code, I'm using docstrings to keep general instructions about models, and it would be very useful if I could display it in the Django admin. The perfect way would be to use the first line of a model's docstring on the index pages, and the whole contents on the list and form pages.

Are there any modules/snippets solving that, or should I simply write my own? ;.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the "perfect way" you described, but there is [django.contrib.admindocs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/admindocs/)

For the "perfect way", you could make a little template filter that returns the docstring of a model, and use that in your overloads or admin/change_form.html and admin/change_list.html.

Correct me if I'm wrong but docstrings are not the perfect place for contents that should be localized.

If you have a rather short amount of text per model to localize, like one or two sentences, here's a few thoughts:

- A short amount of text can be held in a python variable.
- A Python variable can be proxied by django.utils.translation.ugettext.
- A class can hold a python variable.

So I'd try something like:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _

class Foo(models.Model):
    help_text = _(u'Documentation of Foo model to localize')
```

Comment: What would you suggest then as the right place for `help_text` of a whole model?

Comment: It depends on the quantity of text and whether it should be localized or not.

Comment: OK, let's assume it's not a very large amount of text (one or two sentences) and it should be localized.

Comment: Thanks for the details, added a possibility in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this seems to be something that would make sense to be added to the Django models in general -- maybe as a Meta class attribute?